# Adsense not working with Polymer design

Tags: html, polymer, adsense, dart-polymer, polymer-designer-tool

I'm in the middle of a project building a website for a family takeaway, I've managed to get the core design right for what I want.  I now have a problem displaying adsense within my website.

I receive a message in console

> Uncaught Error: adsbygoogle.push(): All ins elements in the DOM with class=adsbygoogle already have ads in them.

please take a look at the website http://tastygrillbristol.uk

> 

```html
          </style> 
      <core-drawer-panel transition id="core_drawer_panel" touch-action>
        <section id="section" drawer>
          <core-header-panel mode="standard" id="core_header_panel">
            <core-toolbar id="core_toolbar">
              <div id="div">Menu</div>
            </core-toolbar>
            <section id="section2">
              <core-menu selected="0" id="core_menu">
                  <core-item id="core_item7" icon="home" label="Home" horizontal center layout><a href="../index.html"></a></core-item>
                  <core-submenu id="core_submenu" icon="list" label="Online Menu">
                    <core-item id="core_item" label="Special Offers" horizontal center layout><a href="../menu.html"></a></core-item>
                    <core-item id="core_item" label="Everything" horizontal center layout><a href="../menu.html"></a></core-item>
                  <core-item id="core_item" label="Burgers" horizontal center layout><a href="../menuburgers.html"></a></core-item>
                  <core-item id="core_item1" label="Kebabs" horizontal center layout><a href="../menu.html"></a></core-item>
                  <core-item id="core_item2" label="Doners" horizontal center layout><a href="../menu.html"></a></core-item>
                  <core-item id="core_item3" label="Pizzas" horizontal center layout><a href="../menu.html"></a></core-item>
                </core-submenu>
                <core-item id="core_item4" icon="shopping-cart" label="Deliver to you" horizontal center layout><a href="../delivery.html"></a></core-item>
                <core-item id="core_item5" icon="perm-phone-msg" label="Call us" horizontal center layout><a href="../callus.html"></a></core-item>
                <core-item id="core_item6" icon="file-map" label="Find us" horizontal center layout><a href="../findus.html"></a></core-item>
                                  <core-item id="core_item6" icon="favorite" label="Follow us" horizontal center layout ><a href="../followus.html"></a></core-item>
              </core-menu>
            </section>
          </core-header-panel>
        </section>
        <section id="section1" main>
          <core-scroll-header-panel condenses id="core_scroll_header_panel" headerHeight="256" condensedHeaderHeight="64">

            <core-toolbar class="tall" id="core_toolbar1">
              <paper-icon-button core-drawer-toggle id="navicon" icon="menu"></paper-icon-button>
              <div flex></div>
        <div horizontal center-justified layout class="bottom indent title" > <p><b><font color=#FF1744>Tasty Grill</font></b></p> </div> 

            </core-toolbar>

              <div class="content" horizontal layout center>    

        <post-card1> 

            <div align="center"><h2 align="center">WELCOME TO OUR WEBSITE, BARE IN MIND WE'RE STILL UNDER CONSTRUCTION</h2><p align="center">Take a look at our online Menu by pressing the Burger <core-icon icon="menu"></core-icon> Button above, or if you know exactly what you want call us now on <p><b><a href="tel:01179522233">(0117)9522233</a></b></p></p></div>


      </post-card1></div>

        <section class="section1" horizontal center-justified layout>

<h1>ADSENSE CODE GOES HERE</h1>

</core-header-panel>
          </core-scroll-header-panel>
        </section>
      </core-drawer-panel>
            </template>
```

Comment: Can you please add some source code? I don't know about AdSense. Do you need to add a specific tag to make the AdSense script work? Did you add this tag inside a Polymer element or somewhere in the entry page (`index.html`)?

Comment: Hello Günter, I've added some Code the best way I Could - Let me know if that doesn't help... Yes I need to add specific Code that Google provided to the HTML, I've added into the entry page rather than a Polymer Element.  Do you think I should have added it into the Polymer Element instead?

Comment: In the source of the linked page it looks like you added the Adsense scripts inside `<my-element>`. I assume that the Adsense code is not compatible with shadow DOM and therefore fails with an error. Try adding it outside of the Polymer element (directly to the entry page).

Comment: Hi Günter, sorry for the massive delay - I haven't had a huge amount of time to look at this lately.. If I put the Adsense code out outside of the Polymer Elements it will display, there is something within polymer stopping this from working.

Comment: Polymer elements introduced shadow DOM. The HTML inside the elements `<template>xxx</template>` is hidden from the outside. Special syntax is necessary for JavaScript/Dart and CSS to get access to elements hidden in shadow DOM. This causes problems with many legacy libraries/frameworks (but is the right direction nonetheless to ensure encapsulation). You can investigate in Chrome devtools (you might need to enable shadow DOM in devtools settings first).

Comment: Obviously the library is not compatible with shadow DOM. Please create a bug report in the libraries issue tracker and please post the link to the issue here after you created it as reference for others.

Comment: Hey @AliHussanAhmed, I just looked at your website and it seems to work for your site (at least I see adsense elements). Obviously you use the polymer element google-adsense. I tried that too, but got no success. May you shortly update your question with your way to solve the problem?

Comment: Hi @Jokus, can you show me your code - I'll have a look or tell me what errors you get in console..

Comment: My Google-Adsense element always throws the error "Uncaught Error: adsbygoogle.push(): All ins elements in the DOM with class=adsbygoogle already have ads in them." I just made a Issue Report to the element (https://github.com/kessiler/google-adsense/issues/1). I think it happens because this element generates the adsense-element in the shadowDOM and can't be found by the script...

Answer (score -3):

Just tested today (2017-05-05) the Ads is working fine within  element (Polymer 1), no warnings, following is the sample code:

```
<paper-card>
    <div class="card-content">
    <p>my content here</p>
    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <!-- AutoSize -->
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-000000000"
     data-ad-slot="000000000"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
    <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
    </div>
</paper-card>
```

Comment: can you show me the website that you have it working in please?